# where should be place the python script to run it from Airflow dag?

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to run a simple dag in Airflow to execute a python file and it is throwing the error can't open the file '/User/....'.

below is the script I am using.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

default_args = {
   'owner': 'airflow',
   'start_date': datetime(2021,3,2),
   'depends_on_past': False,
   'retries': 0
}

dag=DAG(dag_id='DummyDag',default_args=default_args,catchup=False,schedule_interval='@once')

command_load='python /usr/local/airflow/dags/dummy.py '

#load=BashOperator(task_id='loadfile',bash_command='python /Users/<user-id>/MyDrive/DataEngineeringAssignment/dummydata.py',dag=dag)


start=DummyOperator(task_id='Start',dag=dag)
end=DummyOperator(task_id='End',dag=dag)

dir >> start >> end
```

Is there anywhere I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

The file location (`dummydata.py`) is relative to the directory containing the pipeline file (DAG file).

```
dag=DAG(
    dag_id='DummyDag',
    ...
)

load=BashOperator(task_id='loadfile',
                  bash_command='python dummydata.py',
                  dag=dag
                  )
```

**Option 2:**
define your template_searchpath as pointing to any folder locations in the DAG constructor call.

```
dag=DAG(
    dag_id='DummyDag',
    ...,
    template_searchpath=['/Users/<user-id>/MyDrive/DataEngineeringAssignment/']
)

load=BashOperator(task_id='loadfile',
                  # "dummydata.py" is a file under "/Users/<user-id>/MyDrive/DataEngineeringAssignment/"
                  bash_command='python dummydata.py ', # Note: Space is important!
                  dag=dag
                  )
```

For more information you can read about it in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/bash.html#bashoperator)

Comment: Thank you. Tried these two options but still facing the same error.

Comment: How can you be facing the same error as your error is `/User/....` and option 1 is with relative path so there can't be `/User/` unless `/User/` is sub folder of your DAG folder?

Comment: I am trying to run airflow on docker container.

Comment: By same error, I meant "can't open file: dummydata.py"

Comment: Is the path you are referencing included in the container? Please show the traceback of the error

Comment: actually, I didn't mount the path in the container and I guess because of that, it is throwing the error. I will try again after mounting. Thank you for your quick help.